# Row cannot add dynamically using code to Table Layout in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-tablelayout

I just want to add new rows at run time, and I tried using following codes..

java file ::>

```
TableLayout caseTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.caseTable);
TableRow caseRow = new TableRow(this);
caseRow.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);
EditText name = new EditText(this);
name.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
name.setText("Name __");
caseRow.addView(name);
caseTable.addView(caseRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

xml file ::>

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/caseTable"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Case" />
        <TextView android:text="Details" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I want to add new rows below the existing one. I get the code from here at `stackOverFlow`. But it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Simply Use The below code to add TableRow Programatically, perviously it is not working because you are trying to add TableLayout parameter to your EditText.

```
        TableLayout caseTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.caseTable);
        TableRow caseRow = new TableRow(this);
        caseRow.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);
        EditText name = new EditText(this);
        //name.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        name.setText("Name __");
        caseRow.addView(name);
        caseTable.addView(caseRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I get this from here at stackOverflow. Anyway Thank you. :)